# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'App Name' when using Django and Gunicorn on a heroku server

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

What I am trying to do here is setup a sample django app in heroku server. When running the app with gunicorn I get this error

This is what's in the log.

```
2020-02-14T12:11:30.549141+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-02-14T12:11:41.607618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn leadmanager.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-02-14T12:11:44.346394+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-14 12:11:44 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-02-14T12:11:44.347348+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-14 12:11:44 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:54007 (4)
2020-02-14T12:11:44.347349+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-14 12:11:44 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-02-14T12:11:44.351554+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-14 12:11:44 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-02-14T12:11:44.359278+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-14 12:11:44 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-02-14T12:11:45.104994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664943+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-14 12:11:44 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664951+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664953+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664953+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664954+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664954+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664955+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664955+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664955+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664956+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664956+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664957+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664957+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664957+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664958+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664959+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664959+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664961+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664961+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664962+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664962+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664962+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664963+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664963+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664964+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/leadmanager/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664964+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664964+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664965+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664965+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664966+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664966+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664966+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664967+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664967+00:00 app[web.1]: module = import_module(entry)
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664967+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664968+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664968+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664969+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664969+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-02-14T12:11:44.664970+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'leads'
```

In the settings.py I am including the apps like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'rest_framework',
    'leads',
    'frontend',
    'knox',
    'accounts'
]
```

I will attach an image of my folder structure

[image: This is folder structure]

this is working fine in my localhost but when ran on the heroku server with gunicorn results in this "Module not found error"

Sorry I am new to django and was not able to find a solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first leadmanager, like this:

```
web: gunicorn leadmanager.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: I already tried it but getting the same error  "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'leads'"

Comment: The issue I am having here is 

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'rest_framework',
    'leads',
    'frontend',
    'knox',
    'accounts'
]
```

this is not working